# GridViewHeaderRowPresenter scrolls with custom TreeListView control

Tags: wpf, gridviewheader

I have a custom TreeListView - based on the standard TreeView - with the following style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type c:TreeListView}">
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type: c:TreeListView}">
            <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
               <DockPanel>
                  <GridViewHeaderRowPresenter DockPanel.Dock="Top" Columns="{Binding Path=Columns, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                  <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
               </DockPanel>
            </Border>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

As I have no ScrollViewer, the content will not scroll so if the content requires more space than is available, it looks like this:

[image]

So I added a ScrollViewer so that the style now Looks like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type c:TreeListView}">
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type: c:TreeListView}">
            <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
               <ScrollViewer Focusable="False" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding">
                  <DockPanel>
                     <GridViewHeaderRowPresenter DockPanel.Dock="Top" Columns="{Binding Path=Columns, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                     <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                  </DockPanel>
               </ScrollViewer>
            </Border>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

With the content expanded as in the first Image, the Content is not able to scroll, but the column Header scrools as well, which is not wished for :D

[image]

Could anyone please help me so that only the content gets scrolled, and not the columns bound to the *GridViewHeaderRowPresenter*?

Thank you!

**[EDIT]**

Thanks to the related links to the right, I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16162067/wpf-treeview-or-treelistview-headers-horizontal-scrolling-issue?rq=1).

Instead of having the *DockPanel* within the *ScrollViewer* I needed only to have the *ItemsPresenter* inside the *ScrollViewer*. So with the following *Style* it now works.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type c:TreeListView}">
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type c:TreeListView}">
            <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
               <DockPanel>
                  <GridViewHeaderRowPresenter DockPanel.Dock="Top" Columns="{Binding Path=Columns, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                  <ScrollViewer Focusable="False" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                     <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                  </ScrollViewer>
               </DockPanel>
            </Border>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

Many thanks to Nikhil Agrawal for his code!

Comment: why cant you use Tree views own scroll ?

And use Grid instead of Dock panel...

Comment: Hi @Muds, thanks for your input. My first attempt was with a Grid and not the DockPanel. The same result: With no ScrollViewer, the content did not scroll, with a ScrollViewer, the header scrolled as in the example above.

Answer (score 1):

The solution given is incomplete and will only work if you have a fixed width control. By only wrapping the `ItemsPresenter` the header columns will not scroll horizontally if needed. This results in shifted value columns which then mismatch the headers.

I've tried applying `SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Horizontal"` to `GridViewHeaderRowPresenter` but haven't been successfull with that approach.

Instead, you could add a scroll viewer to the `GridViewHeaderRowPresenter` and to the `ItemsPresenter` and then synchronize them. It's not the best solution, but at least it works.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:TreeListView}">
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:TreeListView}">
            <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                <DockPanel>
                    <ScrollViewer DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                  Name="scrollViewerHeader"
                                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                        <GridViewHeaderRowPresenter Columns="{StaticResource gvcc}"/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                  Name="scrollViewerBody"
                                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                        <ItemsPresenter />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </DockPanel>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

And the code behind:

```
public class TreeListView : TreeView
{
    private ScrollViewer _scrollViewerHeader;
    private ScrollViewer _scrollViewerBody;

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        _scrollViewerHeader = (ScrollViewer)Template.FindName("scrollViewerHeader", this);
        _scrollViewerBody = (ScrollViewer)Template.FindName("scrollViewerBody", this);

        _scrollViewerBody.ScrollChanged += (sender, e) =>
                                            {
                                                _scrollViewerHeader.Width = e.ViewportWidth;
                                                _scrollViewerHeader.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(e.HorizontalOffset);
                                            };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way `DataGrid` solves it is it customizes the Template of the `ScrollViewer` to place the `GridViewHeaderRowPresenter` outside the `ScrollViewer` `ScrollContentPresenter`:

https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/blob/059ba38771aef10d2172a3ca0e247dfbfa8cefde/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Wpf/src/Themes/PresentationFramework.Aero2/Themes/Aero2.NormalColor.xaml#L987-L993

This way when the scrollbars scroll, they don't impact the header row.

The `ListView` that uses `GridView` does a similar thing here:
https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/blob/059ba38771aef10d2172a3ca0e247dfbfa8cefde/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Wpf/src/Themes/PresentationFramework.Aero2/Themes/Aero2.NormalColor.xaml#L2628

At the same time they wrap the header row in another `ScrollViewer`, and honestly I don't understand why.

Once I find out more I will expand on this answer. I think this approach if it works is cleaner than synchronizing scroll viewers.